# How to pass a bean from one JSP page to another?

Tags: jsp

Say you have 2 pages:

```
 - one.jsp 
 - two.jsp
```

In `one.jsp` you

```
 - MyBean mb = new myBean();
 - mb.setValue1("value1");
 - mb.setValue2("value2");
```

How can you make `mb` instance available in `two.jsp` on `<input type="submit" name="submit">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you store the bean in the session during the first request, and retrieve it from the session during the second one, or you store value1 and value2 in hidden fields of your form, and recreate the bean using the corresponding request parameters in the second request.

Note that JSPs should not contain Java code. See [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Comment: Excellent answer and link reference. Thank you.